# Missing item from Python List when counting execution time for A* Pathfinding algorithm

Tags: python, list, pygame, path-finding, a-star

I have built an A* Pathfinding algorithm that finds the best route from Point A to Point B, there is a timer that starts and ends post execute of the algorithm and the path is draw, this is parsed to a global variable. so it is accessable when i run the alogrithm more than once (to gain an average time).

the global variable gets added to a list, except when i run the algorithm 5 times, only 4 values get added (I can see 5 times being recorded as the algorithm prints the time after completion). when displaying the list it always misses the first time, and only has times 2,3,4,5 if i run the algorithm 5 times. here is `main.py`

```
import astar


import pygame

def main():
    timing_list = []
    WIDTH = 800
    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, WIDTH))
    for x in range(0, 4):
        astar.main(WIN, WIDTH)
        timing_list.insert(x, astar.full_time)
    print(timing_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and

```
astar.py
from queue import PriorityQueue
from random import randint

import pygame

from timing import Timing

WIDTH = 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, WIDTH))
pygame.display.set_caption("A* Path Finding Algorithm")

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)
GREY = (128, 128, 128)
TURQUOISE = (64, 224, 208)

global full_time

class Spot:
    def __init__(self, row, col, width, total_rows):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.x = row * width
        self.y = col * width
        self.color = WHITE
        self.neighbors = []
        self.width = width
        self.total_rows = total_rows

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.row, self.col

    def is_closed(self):
        return self.color == RED

    def is_open(self):
        return self.color == GREEN

    def is_barrier(self):
        return self.color == BLACK

    def is_start(self):
        return self.color == ORANGE

    def is_end(self):
        return self.color == TURQUOISE

    def reset(self):
        self.color = WHITE

    def make_start(self):
        self.color = ORANGE

    def make_closed(self):
        self.color = RED

    def make_open(self):
        self.color = GREEN

    def make_barrier(self):
        self.color = BLACK

    def make_end(self):
        self.color = TURQUOISE

    def make_path(self):
        self.color = PURPLE

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.width))

    def update_neighbors(self, grid):
        self.neighbors = []
        if self.row < self.total_rows - 1 and not grid[self.row + 1][self.col].is_barrier():  # DOWN
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.row + 1][self.col])

        if self.row > 0 and not grid[self.row - 1][self.col].is_barrier():  # UP
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.row - 1][self.col])

        if self.col < self.total_rows - 1 and not grid[self.row][self.col + 1].is_barrier():  # RIGHT
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.row][self.col + 1])

        if self.col > 0 and not grid[self.row][self.col - 1].is_barrier():  # LEFT
            self.neighbors.append(grid[self.row][self.col - 1])

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return False


def generate_num(x, y):
    return randint(x, y)


def h(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    return abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2)


def reconstruct_path(came_from, current, draw):
    while current in came_from:
        current = came_from[current]
        current.make_path()
        draw()


def algorithm(draw, grid, start, end):
    count = 0
    open_set = PriorityQueue()
    open_set.put((0, count, start))
    came_from = {}
    g_score = {spot: float("inf") for row in grid for spot in row}
    g_score[start] = 0
    f_score = {spot: float("inf") for row in grid for spot in row}
    f_score[start] = h(start.get_pos(), end.get_pos())

    open_set_hash = {start}

    while not open_set.empty():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        current = open_set.get()[2]
        open_set_hash.remove(current)

        if current == end:
            reconstruct_path(came_from, end, draw)
            end.make_end()
            return True

        for neighbor in current.neighbors:
            temp_g_score = g_score[current] + 1

            if temp_g_score < g_score[neighbor]:
                came_from[neighbor] = current
                g_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score
                f_score[neighbor] = temp_g_score + h(neighbor.get_pos(), end.get_pos())
                if neighbor not in open_set_hash:
                    count += 1
                    open_set.put((f_score[neighbor], count, neighbor))
                    open_set_hash.add(neighbor)
                    neighbor.make_open()

        draw()

        if current != start:
            current.make_closed()

    return False


def make_grid(rows, width):
    grid = []
    gap = width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        grid.append([])
        for j in range(rows):
            spot = Spot(i, j, gap, rows)
            grid[i].append(spot)

    return grid


def draw_grid(win, rows, width):
    gap = width // rows
    for i in range(rows):
        pygame.draw.line(win, GREY, (0, i * gap), (width, i * gap))
        for j in range(rows):
            pygame.draw.line(win, GREY, (j * gap, 0), (j * gap, width))


def draw(win, grid, rows, width):
    win.fill(WHITE)

    for row in grid:
        for spot in row:
            spot.draw(win)

    draw_grid(win, rows, width)
    pygame.display.update()


def get_clicked_pos(pos, rows, width):
    gap = width // rows
    y, x = pos

    row = y // gap
    col = x // gap

    return row, col


def main(win, width):
    rows = 50
    grid = make_grid(rows, width)

    start = None
    end = None

    t = Timing()
    run = True
    setup_config = True

    while run:
        draw(win, grid, rows, width)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                setup_config = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False
                    setup_config = False

            while setup_config:

                for x in range(0, 800):
                    row_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
                    col_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
                    spot = grid[row_pos][col_pos]
                    if not start and spot != end:
                        start = spot
                        start.make_start()

                    elif not end and spot != start:
                        end = spot
                        end.make_end()

                    elif spot != end and spot != start:
                        spot.make_barrier()

                t.start()
                for row in grid:
                    for spot in row:
                        spot.update_neighbors(grid)

                algorithm(lambda: draw(win, grid, rows, width), grid, start, end)
                global full_time
                full_time = t.stop()

                setup_config = False
                run = False

    pygame.QUIT

main(WIN, WIDTH)
```

and `timing.py` my timer class

```
import time


class TimerError(Exception):
    """A custom exception used to report errors in use of Timer class"""


class Timing:

    def __init__(self):

        self._start_time = None

    def start(self):

        """Start a new timer"""

        if self._start_time is not None:
            raise TimerError(f"Timer is running. Use .stop() to stop it")

        self._start_time = time.perf_counter()

    def stop(self):

        """Stop the timer, and report the elapsed time"""

        if self._start_time is None:
            raise TimerError(f"Timer is not running. Use .start() to start it")

        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - self._start_time

        self._start_time = None

        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:0.4f} seconds")
        return elapsed_time
```

[image: misses the first timing value from the algorithm execution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

the misterious 5th print is coming from this line, of course

```
full_time = t.stop()
```

With 4 iteractions of your main loop, you reach at this line 5 times. That's the reason you have 5 prints.

You are very right on your comment, when you import astar with the command

```
import astar
```

on your main.py file, you are executing the main(WIN, WIDTH) that you have at the end of astar.py. Thus resulting in 5 prints.

---

```
>>> for i in range(0, 4):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
3
>>>
```

Your main for loop iterates 4 times, each time inserting one element to your empty list. By the way, I would to it like this rather than the cumbersome insert.

```
list.append(astar.full_time) # append inserts at the end of the list
```

I am surprised that you have 5 of the output of the format

```
print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:0.4f} seconds")
```

By the way, I am also wondering why do you have these statements:

```
run = True
while run:
    run = False
```

and a similar statement with a boolean named setup_config and a while. You could get yourself a cleaner code by suppressing this while, since it only executes once. Please, correct me if I am wrong or I am missing something from your context.

Comment: so where is this mysterious 5th elapsed time coming from?

Comment: I've made an edit.

Comment: in all honesty they were there from when i had it set up slightly different from a guide that was being followed, i since adapted it to my needs, they can infact go,

Comment: Check my other answer on that, please.

Comment: I believe its actually the first elapsed time thats the anomaly, and that was coming from the main(WIN,WIDTH) call hiding down at the bottom. this was notices as I included a counter in my print of x, the elapsed time occured before 0 could be printed @Gabriel Pellegrino

Comment: Good job debuggin it =)

Comment: Are this to different answers or did you just add a 2nd answer to get more reputation?

Comment: At the time o writting the second possible answer, we didn't know yet what was the problem. From my perspective, both could lead to finding the bug. Are you bothered with it? @Rabbid76

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino The 2nd answer starts with "EDIT" so it appears to be an extension of the first answer and not an alternative answer. You might want to clarify this in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can also remove the ifs related to the pass commands.

```
def main(win, width):

    rows = 50
    grid = make_grid(rows, width)

    start = None
    end = None

    t = Timing()

    draw(win, grid, rows, width)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pass
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pass

        for x in range(0, 800):
            row_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
            col_pos = generate_num(0, rows - 1)
            spot = grid[row_pos][col_pos]
            if not start and spot != end:
                start = spot
                start.make_start()

            elif not end and spot != start:
                end = spot
                end.make_end()

            elif spot != end and spot != start:
                spot.make_barrier()

        t.start()
        for row in grid:
            for spot in row:
                spot.update_neighbors(grid)

        algorithm(lambda: draw(win, grid, rows, width), grid, start, end)
        global full_time
        full_time = t.stop()

    pygame.QUIT
```

The extra print is mostly like coming from a surprising extra iteraction of this for loop

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
```

Check the value of event, by printing it and check if there's something unusual there.

Comment: thank you for this work, see commont on answer above, where the 5th print (which is actually the first print that is incorrect)